# Why AJAX posting Wordpress not works?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, frontend, posting

I'm  trying to  posting  post via ajax  at  Front  End,  but  I'm  always  failed.

What  I'm  doing  wrong?
here  is  my  code  it  returns  me  0:

HTML

```
<form id="add" name="add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input id="title" type="text" name="post_title" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="my_action">
    <input id="submit" value="Submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

PHP

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-ajax-request', '/js/my_js.js' );
wp_localize_script( 'my-ajax-request', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'MyAjax.action' => 'my_action', 'MyAjax.post_title' => $_POST['post_title'] ) );

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'addpost_ajax_handler' );
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'addpost_ajax_handler' );
function addpost_ajax_handler() {

echo 'reached ajax handler'; // delete this line later

if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) {
    $title = $_POST['post_title'];
    $my_post = array(
        'post_title' => $title
    );
    $result = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $result ) ) echo 'success';
}
die();
}
```

my_js.js

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var data = { 'action': MyAjax.action, 'post_title': MyAjax.post_title };
    $.post(MyAjax.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        alert(response);
    });
});
```

Comment: first you should verify your ajax call reaches your function. Right now you are not returning anything, just a `die();` in the end which is supposed to return 0. How about you echo something first thing into the function.

Comment: If it doesn't, try using an object instead of the serialized datastring which contains your `action` parameter.

Comment: @MSTannu, function should return  post ID. it works if send data without using Ajax

Comment: wp_insert_post returns a value, but to send it back you need to echo it aswell.

Comment: @MSTannu, can you help with this? I don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to all, problem solved. I needed to put the code of php handler in functions.php, instead a custom page)

Answer (score 1):

To check if you actually receive data from the function in php, make some additions:

```
function addpost_ajax_handler() {

    echo 'reached ajax handler'; // delete this line later

    if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) {
        $title = $_POST['post_title'];
        $my_post = array(
            'post_title' => $title
        );
        $result = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
        if ( ! is_wp_error( $result ) ) echo 'success';
    }
    die();
}
```

If you still get just 0, try ensuring you send the action parameter in a way it can be understood:

```
data: { action: my_action, datastr: dataString },
```

Another possible troublemaker could be the relative url, you should use a full url path to ensure your script runs regardless of the page you are on. For that, check http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins and see how they use wp_localize_script to send the correct admin url.

Comment: Your wp_localize_script is a bit off, try this version: `wp_localize_script( 'my-ajax-request', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'action' => 'my_action' ) );`. Note that I removed post_title, because its not going to be set at that point yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can first try with commenting the code of post insertion for a while and just echo the 'reached ajax handler', to verify first of all, the ajax request is successful and then you can move forward to add the post insertion code step by step.

Apart from this, you can add an 'else' part e.g. 
    else {echo 'failed';}
just to verify if there is an issue while creating the new post and it returns 'failed' in response.